# Are there any way to add color to a folder icon on Project panel in JetBrain IDE?

Tags: pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I wonder if there are any way to change the color of a folder on project panel in JetBrain IDE such as PHPStorm which I use.

[image]

There are so my folders in my project and it takes extra time to find the right folder I want to get to.

If I can change the folders I often use, then I can find the folder that I get to more easily.

Comment: use <ctrl> + <shift> + <N> to find by file name, why do you need to explore folders ?

Comment: It's navigate to file menu. Try <ctrl> + <shift> + <A> and type `Navigate to file`

But probably you have different from standard hotkeys